# constraining object to a Joint

Tags: rigging

There are a problem about constrain a group object to a joint.like is
[image]

I want let the group of glasses to be constraint by the head joint.
Could you tell me how to achieve it?
Thank you!!
Hanwen

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you mean you want the glasses to be parented to the head bone, you can parent the glasses to the armature with the "With Empty Groups" option, then select the glasses, go in Edit mode, select all, and in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, select the group to which the glasses are supposed to be part of (it has the name of the bone, like for example Head), and click the Assign button

Comment: You can also parent directly to the bone if you want.

Comment: yes it's just that if he ever decides to join the glasses with the character object, the glasses will already be assigned to the right bone